# Can anyone please explain how do threads implement their own stack in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on my first project involving threads in Java and I would love if someone could explain how the stack works when multithreading in Java please.

Comment: In general, the stack works with variables. Multithreading is how processing is handled. In a microsoft environment the heap is where class object, and functions reside and their variables are on the stack.

Answer (score -1):

In java (as in most os/framework supporting threads) threads are operating within the same process, hence they share heap memory, but each thread has its own stack. local variables (i.e. variables declared inside functions) are allocated on the stack, hence there is no way for a thread to access the local variable of another thread. Note that this statement applies to a variable, not its value. In Java a variable can have a primitive type (int, float, long, double, byte, char, boolean) or have a class type. In the latter case, the variable is a reference (similar to a pointer in C), while two non-primitive variables are on the stack, they can be referencing the same object instance, which is on the heap.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining stack n Java and the code example on coderanch. I'm much clearer now, and I understand why "there is no way for a thread to access the local variable of another thread"

Answer (score -2):

I tried this in my eclipse and sending the below link for your reference and let me know if you need any clarifications

https://coderanch.com/t/566298/java/Implementing-stack-threads